# How do I redirect after a form is submitted, but I have already called a header for sessions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a profile update form that my users can submit from within their profile page. The profile page uses sessions and therefore the header has been set to redirect if they are not logged in. The problem is, I want the form to redirect to their profile page and show the updated information after the form is submitted. I have tried JS redirects, functions in JS and PHP- with no luck. Here is an example of my php

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["Username"])){

}else{
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Here is the form php

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateFName = $_POST['fname'];
        $UpdateLName = $_POST['lname'];
        $UpdateEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $UpdateAddress = $_POST['address'];
        $UpdateCity = $_POST['city'];
        $UpdateZip = $_POST['zip'];
        $UpdatePrimaryPhone = $_POST['primaryphone'];
        $UpdateSecondaryPhone = $_POST['secondaryphone'];
        $UpdatePlayerFName = $_POST['playerfname'];
        $UpdatePlayerLName = $_POST['playerlname'];
        $UpdateTeam = $_POST['team'];
        $UpdatePlayerDOB = $_POST['playerdob'];
        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE user_reg SET Fname = '{$UpdateFName}', Lname = '{$UpdateLName}', Email = '{$UpdateEmail}', Address = '{$UpdateAddress}', City = '{$UpdateCity}', Zip = '{$UpdateZip}', PrimaryPhone = '{$UpdatePrimaryPhone}', SecondaryPhone = '{$UpdateSecondaryPhone}', PlayerFName = '{$UpdatePlayerFName}', PlayerLName = '{$UpdatePlayerLName}', Team = '{$UpdateTeam}', PlayerDOB = '{$UpdatePlayerDOB}' WHERE Username= '$user' ");
    }

?>
```

Here is full page

```
<?php require 'Connections/mysqlilive.php'; ?>

    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["Username"])){

    }else{
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    $user = $_SESSION["Username"];

    $result = $conn->query("select * from user_reg where Username='$user'");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    $_SESSION["Fname"] = $row['Fname'];
    $_SESSION["Lname"] = $row['Lname'];
    $_SESSION["Email"] = $row['Email'];
    $_SESSION["Address"] = $row['Address'];
    $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
    $_SESSION["Zip"] = $row['Zip'];
    $_SESSION["PrimaryPhone"] = $row['PrimaryPhone'];
    $_SESSION["SecondaryPhone"] = $row['SecondaryPhone'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerFName"] = $row['PlayerFName'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerLName"] = $row['PlayerLName'];
    $_SESSION["Team"] = $row['Team'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerDOB"] = $row['PlayerDOB'];
    $_SESSION["Waiver"] = $row['Waiver'];
    $_SESSION["BirthCert"] = $row['BirthCert'];

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateFName = $_POST['fname'];
        $UpdateLName = $_POST['lname'];
        $UpdateEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $UpdateAddress = $_POST['address'];
        $UpdateCity = $_POST['city'];
        $UpdateZip = $_POST['zip'];
        $UpdatePrimaryPhone = $_POST['primaryphone'];
        $UpdateSecondaryPhone = $_POST['secondaryphone'];
        $UpdatePlayerFName = $_POST['playerfname'];
        $UpdatePlayerLName = $_POST['playerlname'];
        $UpdateTeam = $_POST['team'];
        $UpdatePlayerDOB = $_POST['playerdob'];

        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE user_reg SET Fname = '{$UpdateFName}', Lname          = '{$UpdateLName}', Email = '{$UpdateEmail}', Address = '{$UpdateAddress}', City  = '{$UpdateCity}', Zip = '{$UpdateZip}', PrimaryPhone = '{$UpdatePrimaryPhone}',  SecondaryPhone = '{$UpdateSecondaryPhone}', PlayerFName =  '{$UpdatePlayerFName}', PlayerLName = '{$UpdatePlayerLName}', Team =  '{$UpdateTeam}', PlayerDOB = '{$UpdatePlayerDOB}' WHERE Username= '$user' ");

        header("refresh:3; myvbaaccount.php");
        echo("Please wait while we update your account.");
    }

   ?>
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"       href="dreamcodes/social_icons/tsc_social_icons.css" />
   <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/black-ops-one.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Update My Account</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="mainwrap">
   <div id="headerwrap">
    <div id="headertext"><h1 class="header1">valley baseball academy</h1>
        <h3 class="header3">Better.Faster.Stronger.</h3></div>
    <div id="headerpicture"><img src="Assets/VBA black150px.png" alt="vbablack">     <p class="phone">209.380.7721</p></div>
   </div>
   <div id="cssmenu">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="myvbaaccount.php"><span>My VBA Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="contactus.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/valleybaseballinoakdale"><i class="fa    fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/valleybaseball3"><i class="fa fa-twitter-  square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/valleybaseballoakdale"><i class="fa fa- instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="topcontent">
    <div id="tccol1">
        <img class="logo" src="Assets/myvbalogo.png" alt="myvbalogo">
    </div>
    <div id="tccol2"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome <?php echo  $_SESSION['Username']; ?>!</h3></br><h3 class="subheader">Update Your  Account</h3>
    <form action="" method="post" id="updateaccount">
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="fname" type="text" required  class="tfield3" id="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Fname"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="lname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="lname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Lname"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="email" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="primaryphone" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="primaryphone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PrimaryPhone"]; ? >"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="secondaryphone" type="text" required  class="tfield3" id="secondaryphone" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION["SecondaryPhone"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="address" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="address" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Address"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="city" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="city" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["City"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="zip" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="zip" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Zip"]; ?>"></div>
    <h3 class="subheader">Player Information</h3>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="playerfname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerfname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerFName"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="playerlname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerlname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerLName"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="team" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="team" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Team"]; ?>"></div>
    <label>Date of Birth</label><div class="formelement2"><input name="playerdob" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerdob" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerDOB"]; ?>"></div>
    <input name="update" type="submit" class="button" id="update" value="Update  Profile">
    </form>

    </div>
    <div id="tccol3">

    </div>
   </div>
   <h3 class="subheader">Upload Files</h3>
   <div id="bottomcontent">
    <div id="bccol1">
    <div class="formholder">
    <h4 class="subheader">Birth Certificate</h4>
    <P class="ptext">File size limited to 5MB</P>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
    <input type="file" name="UploadBCField" id="UploadBCField" />
    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bccol2">
    <div class="formholder">
    <h4 class="subheader">Sports Physical</h4>
    <P class="ptext">File size limited to 5MB</P>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
    <input type="file" name="UploadSPField" id="UploadSPField" />
    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bccol3"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer" class="subheader">©2016 Chris Carver Baseball LLC</div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This my FIRST question on Stack Overflow, and I just started learning HTML, PHP etc. about 4 weeks ago......be gentle!

Comment: You should learn prepared statements, this is open to SQL injections. You should just do `if(!isset($_SESSION["Username"])){` rather than the `else`; or use `empty`. Where do you set the `SESSION` and where does that `header` live vs. the form update?

Comment: I don't see the problem. The update should only be done if they're logged in, so the original `header()` won't be called. You can put another `header()` after the update, to redirect them to their profile page.

Comment: @chris85 How can I tell if my DB has been affected by SQL injection? Also, I was using the "else" to redirect if the user was not logged in...if I omit this, will it still take them to the login page? I'm not sure what "setting the session" refers to.....

Comment: @chris85 I removed the else statement but still no improvement. Additionally, I cannot test this "live" because I am getting multiple header errors on my login page. I cannot login despite using what I know to be valid credentials. I am continually redirected to my login page. Which is frustrating, because it was working 30 minutes ago...I suck. By the way, the $_SESSION is set on the login page by calling the username and password from the DB.

Comment: Where do you do `$_SESSION["Username"]`? SQL injections vary, you possibly would already know, or could have been a smaller attack. You can always do the inverse of the call rather than making an empty control block. Comment out your `header` and some diagnostic debugging; output expected values and see what is happening.

Comment: @Barmar I tried adding another header after the UPDATE, no luck, ran into multiple header errors.

Comment: @chris85 I did the following; var_dump($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); of a fresh login page and was given the username and password that was testing WELL BEFORE I made several changes...AND when the fields held different values. Additionally, the login page is showing an error on a header call in my connection file, but it doesn't change the header....here is the call to the file <?php require 'Connections/mysqlilive.php'; 
?>         and here is the php           <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "password", "database");

?>

Comment: Don't use the `?>` those can output whitespace which break headers.. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php. Also you are using `session_start` and setting that value somewhere?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I WAS using session_start(); at the top of my pages in it's own line and prior to any header(); commands. I was getting multiple errors no matter what I tried and resorted to removing it from all pages, which solved the error issue. As for leaving off the final ?>, I haven't tested that but my editor (Dreamweaver CC 2015) shows syntax errors when leaving off the closing tag. Regarding the php.net information, if I understand correctly, I cannot omit the closing tag because proceeding HTML. Should I separate PHP from HTML and use require statements on my HTML pages?

Comment: Oh, yea, the code you displayed didn't show any HTML. Maybe update with a bit more of your code, I can't really see the full picture of what is happening yet..

Comment: <form action="" method="post" id="updateaccount">
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="fname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Fname"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="lname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="lname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Lname"]; ?>"></div>

Comment: _“no luck, ran into multiple header errors”_ – if you have PHP error messages appearing, then please _quote them verbatim_, instead of telling us basically nothing useful at all as with that quoted statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have white space on your second line:

```
    <?php require 'Connections/mysqlilive.php'; ?>

        <?php
```

Between the `?>` and `<?php` is outputting to the browser a whitespace which makes the `header` function inaccessible because you've already thrown a `header`.

Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Also note:

> The HTTP status header line will always be the first sent to the client, regardless of the actual header() call being the first or not. The status may be overridden by calling header() with a new status line at any time unless the HTTP headers have already been sent.

So try:

```
<?php require 'Connections/mysqlilive.php';
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["Username"])){
         header('Location: login.php');
         exit();
    }
    $user = $_SESSION["Username"];
    $result = $conn->query("select * from user_reg where Username='$user'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $_SESSION["Fname"] = $row['Fname'];
    $_SESSION["Lname"] = $row['Lname'];
    $_SESSION["Email"] = $row['Email'];
    $_SESSION["Address"] = $row['Address'];
    $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
    $_SESSION["Zip"] = $row['Zip'];
    $_SESSION["PrimaryPhone"] = $row['PrimaryPhone'];
    $_SESSION["SecondaryPhone"] = $row['SecondaryPhone'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerFName"] = $row['PlayerFName'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerLName"] = $row['PlayerLName'];
    $_SESSION["Team"] = $row['Team'];
    $_SESSION["PlayerDOB"] = $row['PlayerDOB'];
    $_SESSION["Waiver"] = $row['Waiver'];
    $_SESSION["BirthCert"] = $row['BirthCert'];
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateFName = $_POST['fname'];
        $UpdateLName = $_POST['lname'];
        $UpdateEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $UpdateAddress = $_POST['address'];
        $UpdateCity = $_POST['city'];
        $UpdateZip = $_POST['zip'];
        $UpdatePrimaryPhone = $_POST['primaryphone'];
        $UpdateSecondaryPhone = $_POST['secondaryphone'];
        $UpdatePlayerFName = $_POST['playerfname'];
        $UpdatePlayerLName = $_POST['playerlname'];
        $UpdateTeam = $_POST['team'];
        $UpdatePlayerDOB = $_POST['playerdob'];
        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE user_reg SET Fname = '{$UpdateFName}', Lname          = '{$UpdateLName}', Email = '{$UpdateEmail}', Address = '{$UpdateAddress}', City  = '{$UpdateCity}', Zip = '{$UpdateZip}', PrimaryPhone = '{$UpdatePrimaryPhone}',  SecondaryPhone = '{$UpdateSecondaryPhone}', PlayerFName =  '{$UpdatePlayerFName}', PlayerLName = '{$UpdatePlayerLName}', Team =  '{$UpdateTeam}', PlayerDOB = '{$UpdatePlayerDOB}' WHERE Username= '$user' ");
        header("refresh:3; myvbaaccount.php");
            echo("Please wait while we update your account.");
    }
   ?>
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"       href="dreamcodes/social_icons/tsc_social_icons.css" />
   <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/black-ops-one.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Update My Account</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="mainwrap">
   <div id="headerwrap">
    <div id="headertext"><h1 class="header1">valley baseball academy</h1>
        <h3 class="header3">Better.Faster.Stronger.</h3></div>
    <div id="headerpicture"><img src="Assets/VBA black150px.png" alt="vbablack">     <p class="phone">209.380.7721</p></div>
   </div>
   <div id="cssmenu">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="myvbaaccount.php"><span>My VBA Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="contactus.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/valleybaseballinoakdale"><i class="fa    fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/valleybaseball3"><i class="fa fa-twitter-  square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/valleybaseballoakdale"><i class="fa fa- instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="topcontent">
    <div id="tccol1">
        <img class="logo" src="Assets/myvbalogo.png" alt="myvbalogo">
    </div>
    <div id="tccol2"><h3 class="subheader">Welcome <?php echo  $_SESSION['Username']; ?>!</h3></br><h3 class="subheader">Update Your  Account</h3>
    <form action="" method="post" id="updateaccount">
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="fname" type="text" required  class="tfield3" id="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Fname"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="lname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="lname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Lname"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="email" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Email"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="primaryphone" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="primaryphone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PrimaryPhone"]; ? >"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="secondaryphone" type="text" required  class="tfield3" id="secondaryphone" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION["SecondaryPhone"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="address" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="address" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Address"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="city" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="city" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["City"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="zip" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="zip" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Zip"]; ?>"></div>
    <h3 class="subheader">Player Information</h3>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="playerfname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerfname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerFName"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="playerlname" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerlname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerLName"]; ?>"></div>
    <div class="formelement2"><input name="team" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="team" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["Team"]; ?>"></div>
    <label>Date of Birth</label><div class="formelement2"><input name="playerdob" type="text" required class="tfield3" id="playerdob" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["PlayerDOB"]; ?>"></div>
    <input name="update" type="submit" class="button" id="update" value="Update  Profile">
    </form>

    </div>
    <div id="tccol3">

    </div>
   </div>
   <h3 class="subheader">Upload Files</h3>
   <div id="bottomcontent">
    <div id="bccol1">
    <div class="formholder">
    <h4 class="subheader">Birth Certificate</h4>
    <P class="ptext">File size limited to 5MB</P>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
    <input type="file" name="UploadBCField" id="UploadBCField" />
    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bccol2">
    <div class="formholder">
    <h4 class="subheader">Sports Physical</h4>
    <P class="ptext">File size limited to 5MB</P>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
    <input type="file" name="UploadSPField" id="UploadSPField" />
    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bccol3"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer" class="subheader">©2016 Chris Carver Baseball LLC</div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

You also should use absolute paths for your locations and should look into using prepared statements with parameterized queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: THANK YOU for all the time you put into this! So far, you're suggestions have put on a path to enlightenment. Kudos to Stack Overflow for building such an awesome community!

Answer (score 0):

This code is viable to SQL injection, you should consider using PDO or mysqli prepared statements. Also, use `die()` or `exit()` when doing a `header()` cause the script continues to execute while the user is browsing another page. Also, the browser does not have to comply with the header request.

However, to answer your question you could do that with a simple GET request.

```
$sql = $conn->query("UPDATE ....
header("Location: profile.php?success=true");
die();
```

Now on the "profile.php"

```
if($_GET['success'] == true){
  // print out the data instead of the form.
} else {
  // print out other forms, etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exit the script after the first `header()`, so that it doesn't try to do a database update if the user isn't logged in.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["Username"])){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```